# UiAutomator Running a test with command line

Tags: junit, android-uiautomator

I'm a beginner and i'm trying to run an uiautomator test clas using a commandline:

C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\androidTest\java>adb shell am instrument -w com.example.user.myapplication/Homologation.java

but it returned the following errors:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for:                 ComponentInfo{com.example.user.myapplication/Homologation.java}
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED:         com.example.user.myapplication/Homologation.java
     at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:1055)
     at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:297)
     at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:91)
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:258)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

someone knows what it means?

Comment: This error appears to be like an incorrect package name entered either in the appium or in your desired capabilities. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears to be like an incorrect package name entered either in the appium or in your desired capabilities. Please check.